# Groovy execute bash script that has ssh

Tags: linux, bash, grails, groovy, ssh

I am trying execute a bash script from my grails app. The script has a ssh call in it. I am using keys to connect between servers.

If I run the script via CLI it works as expected but when I run it via the grails app the script runs but only the part that deals with the local machine. I do not see any output from the remote script.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Bash Script:

```
echo "Starting Data pushed..."
ssh -t -i /path/to/.ssh/id_rsa_remote_user remote_user@remote_server 'sudo /opt/remote_user/script.sh'
echo "Starting Data pushed... Done!"
```

Grails/Groovy code:

```
class CommonService {
    def executeScript(String script, Integer waitTimeInMinutes = 1){
        def sout = new StringBuilder()
        def serr = new StringBuilder()
        Integer exitCode = -1

        def proc
        try {
            proc = script.execute()
            proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
            proc.waitForOrKill(waitTimeInMinutes * 60 * 1000)
            exitCode = proc.exitValue()
        }
        catch(e){
            log.error e.printStackTrace()
            serr << e.toString()
        }


        log.info "Executed Script: ${sout}"
        log.info "Executed Script Extended Output: \n${serr}"

        return [output: sout, error: serr, exitCode: exitCode]
    }
}

Map outcome = commonService.executeScript('/path/to/local/scripts/pushToProduction.sh', waitTime)
```

Comment: take a look at jssh plugin - and also remotessh if you prefer

Comment: Try adding two `-t -t` for sudo to work without at tty. Also you can add `-v` `-vv` or `-vvv` to the ssh command to get debugging output on why it's not working. Though, as suggested, using a java lib to manage the ssh connection is the better choice.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the -t -t option. I would try the java approach but since I don't really have full control of the scripts I kind of have to use the current method.

Comment: @erichelgeson adding the extra -t did the trick. Thanks.